# C# attempt to reentrantly lock something deadlocked, apparent bug

Tags: c#, locking, deadlock, reentrancy

Curious to know if anyone else has seen this problem.  I have an application that locks a statically declared object, this way:

```
lock(Group.IsisGroups)
{
          do some stuff 
}
```

do-some-stuff does various stuff and one of the routines I called attempts to lock the same lock.  Thread deadlocks.

My guess is that this issue is somehow tied to my use of reflection: mid-way down the call stack I do a call to a method by looking it up in the class definition and calling .Invoke().  The call stack that results is this:

```
[In a sleep, wait, or join]  
[External Code]  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.Group.doLookup(Isis.Address gaddr) Line 3774 + 0x13 bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.ReliableSender.GotIncoming(byte type, Isis.Address gaddr, Isis.Address sender, int minStable, Isis.Msg m) Line 10179 + 0x9 bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.ReliableSender.doReceive.AnonymousMethod14(byte type, byte code, int seqn, int truePayLoadLen, int PreFragLen, Isis.Address sender, Isis.Address dest, Isis.Address gaddr, int minStable, int FID, int Fn, int nF, byte[] buf) Line 3120 + 0x80 bytes  
[External Code]  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.Msg.doInvokeSingle(System.Delegate del, byte[] barray, System.Type[] types) Line 11582 + 0x10 bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.Msg.InvokeFromBArray(byte[] barray, System.Delegate del) Line 11527 + 0xf bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.ReliableSender.doReceive(object os, Isis.Group g) Line 10034 + 0x71 bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.ReliableSender.Receive(Isis.Group g) Line 10013 + 0xe bytes  
ConsoleApplication2.exe!Isis.ReliableSender.StartGroupReader.AnonymousMethod__6(object o) Line 9097 + 0xc bytes  
[External Code]
```

So the initial call to `lock(Group.IsisGroups)` is in the top method on the stack `ReliableSender.StartGroupReader` and the code deadlocks when it calls lock in the bottom method, doLookup.  The `[External Code]` blocks are from where I called the reflection `Invoke()` method, and from the call into `lock()` that caused things to deadlock.   Definitely the same object being locked, etc (the object is statically allocated when my class is loaded and is of type `List<Isis.Group>` and while I do add and remove things, the actual List object remains througout.

Any suggestions on what could cause this?

Comment: PS: It doesn't happen every time.  In fact it only happens if I put .NET under a fairly heavy load by launching a few copies of my application simultaneously on my dual-processor Pentium. All of this is the most current release of everything.  So I'm thinking .NET bug of some kind?

Comment: In 99% of cases when people think its a .NET bug it turns out its just some unexpected code behaviour that is quite intended. I'm not sure in this case of what is wrong but I'd tend to discount the thought of it being a .NET bug and thus not your fault.

Comment: Look at the other threads, one of them has acquired the locking object and is stuck on something else.

Comment: Chris, I was at work teaching a class.  Anyhow, I can't tick the "up" arrow because you guys haven't voted me enough points or something.

Comment: Hans, if the top level procedure is inside a lock(x) block, how can some other thread have acquired a lock on (x)?  In effect, my code has a thread that did lock(x) { lock(x); } and the inner lock is blocking, at least according to the VS 2010 debugger.  This is what baffles me.  If the thread locked x at the top of the stack, how can it be waiting to lock x 5 or 6 calls down the stack?  Same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, don't feel like leaving this open, so my "answer" is this:  First, (sorry) Bengie and Hans just don't seem to understand that sure enough, a reentrant lock is malfunctioning.  Second, I suspect that this is happening because of my use of reflection; somehow the context information they use to realize that the lock is being re-locked by the same thread is apparently being impacted.

I'm going to fix this by changing my code to not hold the lock during the initial call; basically, I won't try to acquire this lock reentrantly.

Others who run into this thread should be warned: as far as I can tell, I'm encountering what can only be a .NET bug.  And it isn't very hard to provoke, either.

Answer (score 1):

Am I reading this correctly?

So the initial call to lock(Group.IsisGroups) is in the top method on the stack[...]and the code deadlocks when it calls lock in the bottom method[...]into lock() that caused things to deadlock.Definitely the same object being locked.

Some pseudo-code of your methods that shows how they lock would help, but based on what I read, it sounds like you lock the same object with-in the lock?

*If* I read this correctly, it sounds like this happened

```
lock(ob1)
{
  lock(ob1)
  {
  }
}
```

but you sound quite sure of yourself, so I'm assuming I'm mis-reading that.

either way, some pseudo-code of the methods calling the locks would be nice.  :p

Deadlocks are caused by multiple methods/threads locking objects in a "wrong" order.

Comment: I typically don't write code that way, so I forgot. Anyway, there must be at least two objects getting locked in order for a deadlock to occur. What's the other object and what other methods and threads call the locks?

Comment: Bengie, my code is 100K lines of C# so I doubt you really want it.  Hans, that IS it. This is precisely what I'm saying: a reetrant lock request is hanging.  Bengie, I teach classes on this stuff and wrote a textbook too.  I do know what causes deadlock.  Normally, a reentrant lock method shouldn't hang.  So something is causing the .NET system to become confused and to fail to recognize that this was a reentrant request.  That's my question: does anyone know how they implemented this functionality and, in particular, how to "fool" it?  Because apparently I'm doing so.